# Could not get the file parameter value using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am facing one problem. I am trying to upload file using Angular.js and PHP but I can successfully send the file parameter value but in PHP side I could not get it. I am explaining my code below.

> workspesh.html:

```
<div class="pad-bot-10">
<label for="attachment">Attachment</label>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<input type="file" name="documentlink" id="documentlink" ng-model= "subdata.form.documentlink" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedHosFile(this)" class="file">
 <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Attachment" id="documenturl">
 <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Attachment</button>
 </span> </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

> workspeshController.js:

```
    $scope.uploadedHosFile = function(element) {     
            var files = element.files;
            var filename=files[0]['name'];
            var filetype=filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            var size=files[0].size;
            if ($.inArray(filetype, ["php", "exe"] ) != -1) {
                alert("Please upload document or image only !!");
                return false;
            }else if (size > 10485760) {
                alert("File size shouldn't be more than 10MB !!!");
                return false;
            }else{
                var allHosImg=filename;
                $scope.hosfiles = element.files;
                document.getElementById('documenturl').value = allHosImg;
            }
        };
    $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'php/myworkspesh.php?action=saveAddEvent',
            processData: false,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            transformRequest:function(){
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("documenturl", $scope.hosfiles);
                return formData;  
            },
            data : $scope.form,
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

> myworkspesh.php:

```
class Myworkspesh{
   public function saveAddEvent($postData){
        $url = "myworkspaceapi.php?action=saveAddEvent";
        $numfile = 0;
        print_r($_FILES);exit;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $response;
    }
}
$obj = new Myworkspesh();
$action = (isset($_GET['action']))?$_GET['action']:'';
if(method_exists($obj,$action)){
    $obj->$action($_POST);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

> myworkspaceapi.php:

```
$action = (isset($_GET['action']))?$_GET['action']:'';
class MyworkspaceApi{
  public function saveAddEvent(){
        $documenturl = ($_REQUEST['documenturl'] != 'undefined')?$_REQUEST['documenturl'] : '';
        echo json_encode($documenturl);
    }
}
$obj = new MyworkspaceApi();
$action = (isset($_GET['action']))?$_GET['action']:'';
if(method_exists($obj,$action)){
    $obj->$action($dbobj);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Here In PHP side script I could not get any file value. Here I need to get the total file value and will upload it into the local folder.

Comment: can you please show your angularjs request

Comment: I have already posted. Please check it.

Comment: did you really get the call at your file ?
try printing some debugging text in your php file.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried . Here I have ignored the other parameter and those are passing successfully to the PHP side.

Comment: @subhra please show your network request

Answer (score 0):

check the value of "post_max_size" and "max_file_uploads" in php.ini. If the size of uploaded file bigger than this two configures,you would receive nothing in your server side.